# pandas: list items converted to Decimals when writing csv. Cannot parse it back with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I had a DataFrame with a column, in which each cell contained a list of Decimals like `[Decimal('1'), Decimal('3')]`. Then I wrote it into a csv file with `pd.to_csv`. Now I am trying to parse it with `pd.read_csv` and get a string like `"[Decimal('1'), Decimal('3')]"` instead of a real list of Decimals. What should I do to get real lists instead of string literals for such lists in my DataFrame when I read back from a csv file?

Comment: Just from curiosity why is your list of decimals not `[1.0, 3.0]` rather than this format you are describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **pd.to_csv** only returns the resulting csv format as a string. Otherwise returns None. So you have to convert string to list manually. Please refer to my example below, hope it is similar to what you are asking.

```
import json
d = {'col1': [[1.0,2.0], [1.0,2.0]], 'col2': [3.0, 4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
df_read_back = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters = { 'col1' :lambda x: json.loads(x)})
```

Comment: Thank you, GenZ. It works fine! But what if Decimals appear in the csv when I create it?

Comment: I think Decimals is string type. I really don't understand your question.